# how to resize infowindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have some markers at my map with infowindow for each of them. Map is small, about 260px/260px, so infowindow popup is too big. I want to resize this popup to smaller size, but with no effect. Here is my code - i tried with maxWidth - no effect, and with infowindow.resize(50,50) -> error "infowindow is not a function":

```
                for (var i = 0; i < arraylng.length-1; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylng[i], arraylat[i])
                    });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: " ",
                    maxWidth: 10
                  });     

              makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker, i);

                markers.push(marker);
                }
                var currentMarker;

            function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker, i) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                 currentMarker=marker;
                 Googleapi.GetAddressMarker(arrayidunion[i], setmarker); // webservice
              });
            }

            function setmarker(result)
            {
            var address1 = result;
                infowindow.setContent(address1);
                infowindow.open(map, currentMarker);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved! If somebody will have the same problem as mine, look at this:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html
works perfectly :)